# Android studio emulator white screen

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've Installed the newest version of Android studio, including the newest version of HAXM, ndk, sdk and whatever other related dependencies it installs. Intel Virtualization bios setting thingy I can't remember the name of is enabled and I have no trouble in virtual box and such.

I created an empty activity and tried testing it on the phone, works perfectly. Then I tried it on the emulator and there is a problem when it is hardware accelerated. It just opens a white window. The android studio displays 0 errors and thinks it ran the app properly. The graphics card I have is a gtx 1060 6gb. When it is software accelerated it works but is so slow I would rather use a chisel on a rock to draw the application usage.

So if someone knows a fix it would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: Happened to me after updating HAXM to the latest recently (01/2018) on the Mac. White screen. No response to taps. Can't close the process by usual means. qemu_system-x86-64 shows 102.7% CPU utilization.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well I have discovered that in order to solve the issue you have to go to the sidebar menu click **More**>**Settings**>**OpenGL ES Renderer** and(in my case) set it to **Angle(D3D11)** or **Angle(D3D9)** or **Swiftshader**. After that you simply restart the emulator and the issue should be gone.

For me *Desktop native OpenGL* and *Autodetect based on host*(which probably sets it to the first thing) don't work and leave you with a white screen.

Comment: Desktop native OpenGL worked for me.  I only had this problem on the Android 6 x86_64 emulator... others worked without issues.  Sadly it is massively slower to run now :(

Comment: This works! Thanks mate this fixed 2 issues, 1) the one above and 2) System UI kept crashing

Comment: Thank you! Solved my case on macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 4):

In case someone finds this useful, you can set software acceleration as below and this solved the issue for me on Mac OS. (OP also mentions it works with software acceleration)

1. Tools > AVD Manager
2. Select virtual device
3. Click on Edit (pencil icon for me)
4. Click "Show Advanced Settings"
5. Look for Emulated Performance - Graphics
6. Select "Software" option

Answer (score 0):

Current version of the emulator (27.1.3) doesn't work for me. The emulator just shows a white screen. Even playing with the gpu in the .ini configuration didn't work.
Once I downgraded to 26.1.4 (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-4266726.zip) the emulator started working again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Android Emulator is somehow conflicting with the NVidia Web driver on Mac OS. I had the latest NVidia Web driver (378.05.05.25f04) installed and I was having this same problem - the white screen whenever I used Desktop Native rendering (or left it at the automatic default which selects that as well).

I tried the Swift Shader as well, it works but the performance is abysmal!

On a hunch, I switched back to the OS X Default Graphic Driver from the Nvidia Pref Pane in Apple menu settings, and the Desktop Native driver is now working great after the computer restart!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem can happen to t[he lightning fast Microsoft Android Emulators utilizing Hyper-V that work on both Intel and AMD CPU based PCs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/).  The solution is in the same line as the accepted answer.  For those who use Microsoft Android Emulators and land here by searching "android emulator white screen", here is the screenshot showing how to solve the problem by changing the default hw.gpu.mode from the default "auto" to "mesa":

[image]

Answer (score -1):

So sorry
Check your onCreate method in your MainActivity.java, it should have setContextView(R.layout.activity_main)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).