# Emulator Not Booting (White Screen)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After I updated the Android Emulator to version 27.0.1 I'm getting a white screen and the emulator does not even boot.

Here is a acreenshot of the behaviour:

[image: white screen]

No boot logo or anything is appearing on screen.

This is a screenshot of the emulator settings:

[image: settings]

None of the emulators, even the ones I had before upgrading are working.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166968) but I couldn't find the OpenGL ES Render option,

I am working under macOS 10.12.6 and a GTX 1060 6GB graphics card.

Do you know of a solution, possibly without slowing down the emulator too much?

I tried uninstalling both Android Emulator and HAXM Installer and reinstalling them but it did not work. Still the same issue.

EDIT:

The emulator has been updated to 27.0.2, Still not getting past the white screen

I managed to fix that by selecting SwiftShader as the OpenGL Renderer, although performance is so poor it is barely usable, hope a update that fixes the problem will be released soon.

Comment: I have the same issue (Windows 10, GTX950M, i7) and I can only get that to happen on ARM devices. Try running an x86 emulator instead

Comment: @Zoe all my emulators are x86 actually, so the problem does not seem to be it, gonna test with an ARM one

Comment: tried also with ARM and x86_64 but no luck either

Comment: Could be a problem with the emulator itself (a bug). I noticed this after the emulator update, could be related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Android Emulator update finally fixed the issue. So make sure you updated all the SDK tools

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean/resync your project and to uninstall Android Studio? This solved my problem. Otherwise you could try to use the Genymotion Emulator while Android Studio is fixing this problem.