# Android Emulator for arm won't start on M1 processor

Tags: android, emulation, apple-m1

I've downloaded Canary to write code on Apple M1 and all worked perfectly until I changed the option as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127545/android-studio-emulator-white-screen/51982851) (OpenGL ES Renderer and set it to Angle(D3D11) or Angle(D3D9) or Swiftshader) to prevent a white screen on the emulator.

Now it's just won't start, and the app won't run on a physical device as well. When I start the emulator, app with "exec" letters on it appears in the Dock and after it, Android Studio throws Emulator timeout error - all of this is in the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUa2M.png)

What did to fix this:

- tried to run a different App - the same thing
- deleted .lock files in .android/avd folder
- deleted .img files .android/avd folder
- completely deleted canary and reinstalled Artcic Fox 2020.3.1 beta 5
- tried to use arm64 emulator which was added to Android Studio stable version

Comment: which version are you using? Android Studio Artic Fox (???)

Comment: Version 2020.3.1 beta 5 - added info to the question

Comment: After multiple reinstallations of AS different versions and multiple reboots the problem resolved itself somehow